# How can i grep the last group of lines using awk?

Tags: awk, grep, tac

I have the following contents in my file file.txt

```
Start
1
2
3
5
end
Start
a
b
c
d
end
```

How do i use only awk to get the section which is at the end from "start" to "end" as follows?

```
Start
a
b
c
d
end
```

Tried efforts:

```
awk '/Start/ {{ f = 1;n++ }} f && n == 2; /end/ {{ f = 0 }}' file.txt
```

Comment: if you already know how to get first match, here's a tip to get the last match: use `tac` to reverse input file linewise, adjust your code to get first match, then use `tac` again

Comment: i tried the following command awk '/Start/ {{ f = 1;n++ }} f && n == 2; /end/ {{ f = 0 }}' file.txt

Comment: But i dont want to give any number "2" since i may not know how many occurrences happens.

Comment: @Sandeep, Thank you for posting your efforts, kindly do add them in your question since comments are NOT meant for showing efforts, keep it up, cheers.

Comment: What if you had a `start` line after the last `end` line in the input? Should from the last `start` to end-of-file be printed or the block of text between the 2nd-last `start` and the last `end`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tac` + `awk` solution, could you please try following.

```
tac Input_file | awk '/^end/{found=1} found; /^Start/{exit}' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** `tac` will print Input_file in reverse order(from bottom to up manner), then passing its output to `awk` command and in `awk` code printing from first occurrence of `end` to till first occurrence of `start`. Exiting from `awk` code when first occurrence of `start` is found, again this output is being send to `tac` which will reverse the output and post it in original form of Input_file.

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` one could try like but it assumes that there is NO discrepancy(means after each start there is end keyword present in OP's Input_file else it will give false positive results) in start and end keywords appearance.

```
awk -v RS= '{sub(/.*Start/,"Start")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "Start" { s = ""; p = 1 }
p { s = s $0 ORS }
$1 == "end" { p = 0 }
END { printf "%s", s }' file
```

```
Start
a
b
c
d
end
```